# selected row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I have two table in sql server as follow

```
PatientDetail - 1st table name     
PatientId --- primary key
firstname
lastname

Patexam - 2nd table name
PId ---- foreign key of first table PatientId
Exam
```

I have one gridview in the page which shows all the column of first table as below

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDoctorList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PatientId" HeaderText="PatientId" SortExpression="PatientId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="firstname" HeaderText="firstname" SortExpression="firstname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="lastname" HeaderText="lastname" SortExpression="lastname" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="sex" HeaderText="sex" SortExpression="sex" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PatientId],[firstname], [lastname], [sex],  FROM [PatientDetails]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have one button with the text value = "formatric3d"
Now when i select one row in gridview and then click on button with

```
value = "formatric3d",
```

so on click event I want to insert the selected row `patientid` as well as `button text value = "formatric3d"` into the table name Patexam.

That means PId equal to `PatientId` which is selected on gridview and Exam equal to `button text value = "formatric3d"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you want?

```
      <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExam" Text="formatric3d" OnClick="Exam_ClickHandler" />
                <asp:GridView ID="gvDoctorList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPID" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("PatientId") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PatientId" HeaderText="PatientId" SortExpression="PatientId" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="firstname" HeaderText="firstname" SortExpression="firstname" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="lastname" HeaderText="lastname" SortExpression="lastname" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="sex" HeaderText="sex" SortExpression="sex" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

      <h3>Patient Exams</h3>
            <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dtlExams">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("Exam") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
//////////////// tree view 
    <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="tvExams">
        </asp:TreeView>
```

On code behind page:

```
  protected void Exam_ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDoctorList.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chk");
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                string patientId = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblPID")).Text;
                string exam = ((Button)sender).Text;

                ///your insertion query goes here.
                ///

                GetPatientExams(patientId);
            }

        }
    }

    protected void Patient_ExamHandler(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string patientId = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        GetPatientExams(patientId);


    }



  private void GetPatientExams(string pid)
{

    DataTable exams = "Get exam data from db by pid";

    dtlExams.DataSource = exams;
    dtlExams.DataBind();
```

//////////////// tree view 
        TreeNode tnnn;

```
    foreach (DataRow row in exams.Rows)
    {
        tnnn = new TreeNode(exams["PRODSHORT"].ToString());
        tvExams.Nodes.Add(tnnn);
    }

}
```

Comment: One more help....Now after checking on one row....I want to see the inserted data for particular patient....that means with one patientid there may be more than one exam value...so i want to show all the exam for selected patientid....could you please let me how it is possible with code. thanks a lot

Comment: Yes sure. You would need to add another databound control like gridview to display the data.

Comment: if i want to show in treeview then how the code should be like?Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer.. somthing like this will do it for you. Vote up if this works for you. Happy programing :P

Comment: yes like this...but i want to show in tree view so how it will be possible?

Comment: I have firstname from one table and examination from another table as i mention on question...so how can i get that value in tree view?

Comment: I want to show in tree view only the select patient in the gridview not entire table.....

Comment: Yes the above code will populate data for selected Patient only. You see the Exmas Link Button in against each patient. Clicking that will display the data.

Comment: private void GetPatientExams(string pid)
        {
            DataTable exams = new DataTable("select Exam from     PatExam where PId = pid");

            dtlExams.DataSource = exams;
            dtlExams.DataBind();
        }

Comment: I try your code but it is not showing the data in datalist box....it not showing any error but it is not displaying anything after clicking on button....

Comment: i dont want to show on button click...but when the checkbox is check at that time i want to show treeview or datalist...show how this would be possible?